# Xlemmaseparator and Xendlemmaseparator

Tags: reledmac

Here are two problems:

1. Can not change separator locally. `]` means 'is replaced' when word is missing I can just use `-` or `>` in place of `]` if I could change `\rbacket` locally on each call place. Is a way to do this?
2. `\Xendlemmaseparator` has no effect at all;

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia,fontspec,xunicode,etex}
%\usepackage{libertineotf}
\setmainlanguage{english}

\usepackage[series={A}]{reledmac}
\Xarrangement{paragraph}
\arrangementX{paragraph}
\Xendlemmaseparator[A]{;}

\begin{document}
    \beginnumbering
        \pstart
            Left \edtext{side}{\Xlemmaseparator[A]{\textminus}\lemma{side}\Afootnote{C}} paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph.
            \edtext{Other side}{\Xlemmaseparator[A]{\textdagger}\lemma{plus}\Afootnote{C}}
        \pend
        \pstart
            Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.
        \pend
    \endnumbering

\end{document}
```

What I expect is critical notes separated by ';'.

Comment: The separator is for use between the lemma and the node, isn't it? Not between notes?

Comment: To be honest, I don't really understand the first part of your question at all.

Comment: I don't think you can change the separator locally. But I also don't see why you would want to since it would clearly make things very, very confusing for readers. Perhaps you could clarify your question a bit. At least the second part is straightforward.

Comment: in some editions ']' means--this text is replaced by; '< something in A' means that 'something' is missing in A version of document; '> something2 in B' means there B version of document adds 'something'..so instead of using 'nosep' option and writing by hand <, > signes we coud just redefine ']' and have 2 sort commands for > and < versions...this versions can have empty lemma field in many cases...locally redefining ] will make typing less :)

Comment: and again something like '(X)noteseparator(X)' for paragraphed notes can be usefull..will make typing less

Comment: If the lemma is empty, can't you use `nosep` and put the symbol in place of the lemma? I guess this could be done. You could define a command to eat it in the text and not in the notes, for example. [Possibly.]

Comment: yes i was wrong...no emty lema ..Just in C or B in Xfootnote whatever version has omitted/added text... like \edtext{some}{\lemma{some}\Afootnote{C}}..This will result: 2 some < C

Comment: yes you are right. we can do : \newcommand{\ismissing}[2]{
  \edtext{#1}{
    \lemma{#1 <}\Afootnote[nosep]{#2\hspace*{-6pt}}
  }
} and \ismissing{missing text}{in C;}

Comment: please ! do not use negative hspace after a [nosep]. Use the setting of `\Xendinplaceoflemmaseparator` / `\Xinplaceoflemmaseparator` ! And if you want specific separator, open a github issue, I will add an optional argument in footnote.  https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/issues

Comment: \Xendinplaceoflemmaseparator / \Xinplaceoflemmaseparator can this be changed for differents Xfootnotes of same series? I use one --A and have 4 kind of commands for it: 1. normal as defined with lemma... 2. without lemma an nosep.and 3 . 4. for omitted text in variant(--) and aded text in variant (+) with lemma and nosep option

Comment: the \Xend \X… commands are for a full series. But I can quite easily add feature for specifice not of one series (optional argument of Aend). Just open an issue with full MWE and explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues:

- the separator is used between the lemma and the note - not between notes;
- `\Xendlemmaseparator` only affects endnotes - not footnotes. `\Xlemmaseparator` is used for footnotes.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[series={A}]{reledmac}
\Xarrangement{paragraph}
\arrangementX{paragraph}
\Xlemmaseparator[A]{;}

\begin{document}
\beginnumbering
  \pstart
    Left \edtext{side}{\Afootnote{C}} paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph.
    Left \edtext{sides}{\Afootnote{C}} paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph.
    \edtext{Other side}{\Afootnote{C}}
  \pend
  \pstart
    Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.
  \pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: semicolons in notes]

## EDIT

The first question is simply answered: you cannot change the separator locally because the definition is global.

`\Xlemmaseparator` and `\Xendlemmaseparator` define commands which are set up in such a way that any changes are global. They use, for example `\gdef` rather than `\def` which means that the changes are effective not just inside the current group (i.e. locally).

However, the package author would be better explaining this because I've already got the code wrong once and clearly don't understand what is going on.

But the upshot is that the `\global`s (e.g. `\csgdef` or `\gdef` or `\xdef` etc.) mean that even if you change the value within a group i.e. locally, the change will be applied globally.

Comment: thanks..how about the firts question...can have different  than ']' for the same series of Xfootnotes?

Comment: It is a global definition. You cannot make a local change.  Obviously, you can use different values for different series. But you can't use different values for the same series.

Comment: Please see edit. I've added a brief explanation with the code from the package which includes the `\global`isation macros.

Comment: @cfr:no the setting of the value is done in `\setcommand@series`, not in `\newhookcommand@series` which only create the setting command. But indeed, in `\setcommand@series` I use a `\gdef` to store the setting.

Comment: @Maïeul Thanks. Obviously you are right and now I look, I realise I don't understand how the code works.

Comment: @cfr the code is quite complex, but explained in the .dtx file / pdf documentation. Just know that \newhookcommand@series create user commands like `\Xendfoo` which call a `\gdef`,via the `\setcommand@series`.

Comment: I know ;-) An other point that make this calling of setting before each individual note inoperate is the fact the setting which is important is the one when doing \doendnotes{A}. That is why indeed there is the possibility to have setting for particular note with optional argument.